# how to retrieve image with mongodb(mongoose)/react?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, reactjs, mongoose

I want to save image file using mongodb on server side.
and I want to display this (saved) image on front side.

Below is my server side code.

```
const Video = new Schema({
    ...file owner, file path, etc,.
    screenshot: {
        type: Buffer
    }
});

// Extract thumbnail by using ffmpeg.
    let resDir = __dirname + '/resources/';
    let videoFullPath = resDir + 'videos/' + newFileName;
    let ssFullPath = resDir + 'screenshots/' + newFileName + '.png';
    let execCommand = 'ffmpeg -i ' + videoFullPath +
                      ' -f image2 -t 0.001 -ss 1.0 ' + ssFullPath;
    childProcess.exec(execCommand);

    // Save Video information DB.
    let newVideo = new Video({
        ...file ownef, file path, etc,.
        screenshot: ssFullPath,
    });
    newVideo.save((err, data) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        return res.json({success: true});
    });
```

And below is my front side code. (movieClipData is mongoDB object)

```
const imgSrc = 'data:image/png;base64,' + movieClipData.screenshot.data;
<img src={imgSrc}/>
```

I think file type(base64, binary...) cause this issue.
so I tried to convert file type to base64, but it didn't work. (maybe I wouldn't have done it properly...)

Can you explain how to match file type?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow.  Can you please give more detail than "but it didn't work"  Do you have an error message?

Comment: @ruby_newbie, there is 'net::ERR_INVALID_URL' log on my browser console..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a `data` property on your `movieClipData.screenshot` object from what you're describing about your backend.

Did you try to use it as an url directly, since you have `screenshot: ssFullPath`, the `screenshot` isn't a `Buffer` as described in the Schema, but a string of the filepath saved by ffmpeg.

```
<img src={movieClipData.screenshot} />
```

Comment: I tried src={movieClipData.screenshot}, and "<img id="screenshot590f291b2f068a0b1e768f95" class="screenshot" src="[object Object]">" this log printed.

Comment: and I check movieClipData.screenshot object. "Object {type:"Buffer", data: Array(225988)}" is printed.

Comment: It seems we're missing a few steps from your backend processing. Can you add more details please?

Comment: before save my image with mongoose, I have tried this.    **`fs.writeFile(ssFullpath, originScreenshotData, 'base64', function(err) { console.log(err); });`**

Comment: I'll need to see what's your code in the back end that delivers the image to the front end, and the one in the front end that receives the image.